# Mocha From Nightwatch assert.containsText fails

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, nightwatch.js

Pretty new at this.  Running the **Using Mocha From Nightwatch** example http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-mocha, verbatim test -- it's failing.  Can't figure out why.

The browser launches and "nightwatch" is entered into google search....

```
$ npm test

> jbserver@0.0.101 test /var/www/html/3jbserver
> node ./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch -c ./test/nightwatch.json ./test/google.test.js

  1) Google demo test for Mocha with Nightwatch uses BDD to run the Google simple test

  0 passing (8s)
  1 failing

  1) Google demo test for Mocha with Nightwatch uses BDD to run the Google simple test:
     Testing if element <#main> contains text: "Night Watch". - Expected "Night Watch" but got: ""
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/google.test.js:30:17)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/google.test.js:20:7)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

In nightwatch.json...

```
  ...
  "test_runner" : {
    "type" : "mocha",
    "options" : {
      "ui" : "bdd",
      "reporter" : "list"
    }
  }
  ...
```

google.test.js is exactly the given example

```
...
it('uses BDD to run the Google simple test', function(client) {
  client
    .url('http://google.com')
    .expect.element('body').to.be.present.before(1000);

  client.setValue('input[type=text]', ['nightwatch', client.Keys.ENTER])
    .pause(1000)
    .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch');
});
...
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch -c ./test/nightwatch.json ./test/google.test.js"
   ...
```

running with (npm) selenium-standalone.

Answer (score 2):

Tests tend to break when you use something as general as #main (which is the whole page of google, a bit much). Documentation in Nightwatch could be a bit better.

You could do this instead, to see how Nightwatch works. I've used a more specific selector.

```
.assert.containsText('#rhs_title span', 'Night Watch');
```

This will select the `span` inside the #rhs_title element, and check if it contains 'Night Watch'.

Try to avoid `.pause` and instead use `.waitForElementVisible(time, 'element')`. Pause will force to pause for 1000ms, whilst `.waitForElementVisible` will wait **maximum** 1000ms, but the test will continue if the element is found. This saves precious time.

It would together look like:

```
.waitForElementVisible(1000, '#rhs_title span')
.assert.containsText('#rhs_title span', 'Night Watch');
```

Comment: Hello, what is #rhs_title span? Can I use name, xpath or id of the element here?

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a test setting

```
"test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "test_runner" : {
    "type" : "mocha",
    "options" : {
      "ui" : "bdd",
      "reporter" : "list"
    }
  },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
```

Now for assert

```
it('uses BDD to run the application test', function(client) {
      client
        .url('url')
        .expect.element('body').to.be.present.before(1000);

      client.setValue('input[type=text]', ['ranjan', client.Keys.ENTER])
        .pause(1000)
        .assert.containsText('#main', 'ranjan');
    });
```

This code woke for me, Please change the URL as google